# A strange lier that tells truth on 7th day of the week.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Q)Ravi is strange liar. He lies on 6 days of the week, but on the seventh day he always tells the truth. He made the following statements on 3 successive days:
**Day1: "I lie on Mon and Tue."

Day2: "Today, it's Thu, Sat, or Sun" 

Day3: "I lie on Wed and Fri."

On which day does Ravi tell the truth?**

(A)Mon 
(B)Tue 
(C)Wed 
(D)Thu

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Day1+Day3 can't both be false, because then Ravi would tell the truth on two days.  Hence either Day1 or Day3 is true, and Day2 is false.
2. If Day3 is false, then Day1 is true.  Since Day3 is false, the true day (Day1) must be Wed or Fri.  But then Day2 is Thu or Sat, and Day2 is true, which is impossible.
3. Hence Day3 is true and Day1 is false.  Since Day1 is false, the true day (Day3) must be Mon or Tue.  But then Day2 is Sun or Mon.  Since Day2 is false, Day2 must be Mon, which makes Day3 Tue.

Answer: Tuesday.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume all three things he says is a lie and see if that's consistent:

- **Day1:** If this is a lie, then he tells the truth either on Monday or Tuesday.
- **Day2:** If this is a lie, then it must be Mon, Tue, Wed, or Fri.
- **Day3:** If this is a lie, then he must tell on the truth on Wed or Fri.

Clearly this is not consistent, because **Day1** and **Day3** cannot both be lies (likewise they cannot *both* be the truth since he only tells the truth one day of the week).  So now, just assume one is the truth, let's assume **Day1**, he's telling the truth and **Day3** he's lying.

- **Day1:** If this is the truth, then we know for sure he lies on Mon and Tue.
- **Day3:** If this is a lie, then he tells the truth either on Wed or Fri
- If we assume **Day1** is the truth and **Day3** a lie, then **Day1** is either Wed or Fri meaning that **Day2** is either Thu or Sat.  This is inconsistent with **Day2** being a lie.

This means that **Day1** must be a lie and **Day3** must be the truth.  If **Day1** is a lie, then he tells the truth on Mon or Tues which makes **Day3** either Mon or Tues, which makes **Day2** either Sun or Mon.  **Day2** cannot be Sun, but it *could* be Mon (since he definitely lies on **Day2**).  This means:

1. **Day1:** Sun (a lie).
2. **Day2:** Mon (a lie).
3. **Day3:** Tues (the truth).

So he tells the truth on Tuesday.